# Why can't we sign a message using a public key and get the private key?

Tags: private-key, signature, public-key, message

I have just learnt how signing of messages works in ethereum. You take a message, then sign it using a private key to get a signed message. And using the message and the signed message you can get the public key of the private key that signed the message.

Why can we not do the reverse. Sign a message with a public key and get the private key from the message and the signed message?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography Happy reading :P (The wiki is just a starter)

Comment: Thank you for the link. I have also just read the difference between signing and encrypting and now I understand more.

Comment: The public key come from the private key.

Comment: In the public key cryptosystem you sign with the private key and verify with the public key. Since public keys are public and known by everyone it doesn't make much sense to be able to sign a message with them.